# Implement a Kivy Button mouseover event

Tags: python, kivy

I am making a GUI that will have two buttons. I want to perform a sort of Animation on both of those when someone **hovers** over them.

Now, I know that using `Window.bind(mouse_pos=my_mouse_pos_func)` is a workaround since no `on_mouse_hover` is available for `button.bind()` like `on_press` and `on_release`. But that isn't working for me since I cannot specify which widgets in my screen to bind my function when using `Window.bind()`. Doing this works in a way but only if I get the cursor in my main window.

I have searched for this a lot and in almost 90% of the results I found people recommeding `Window.bind()`. And the other 10% are workarounds but were really unclear to me, for e.g workarounds like "listening for mouse events" and stuff like that.

Sorry, as I am being able to provide any code as I am quite clueless as to what to show. If anyone knows any simple workarounds to this, their help will be absolutely appreciated

Comment: https://gist.github.com/opqopq/15c707dc4cffc2b6455f <- here's an example (not mine) of how you can use Window.bind to do what you want, in this case by making a mixin class you can use with any widget.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an older post, but just a follow-up in case someone (like me) has the same problem and finds their way here over Google. @John Anderson's solution works, but it seems easier to me to define a class for those buttons you want to display the desired behaviour and then use `Window.bind()` in *its* `__init__()`, e.g.

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyButton(Button):
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouseover)

def on_mouseover(self, window, pos):
    if self.collide_point(*pos):
        # desired behaviour
```

That way there's no need to keep the list John mentions.

Answer (score 1):

I use the mentioned `Window.bind()` in the `__init__()` method of my app as:

```
    Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)
```

Then in the `on_mouse_pos()` method, I use the `collide_point()` method to determine if the mouse is over any of the `Buttons` in question:

```
def on_mouse_pos(self, window, pos):
    for butt in self.root.ids.butt_box.children:
        if butt.collide_point(*pos):
            # do something here
```

You just need a list of the `Buttons` you want to check (I use the children of a container).